# change php code visually

Tags: php, dreamweaver

My client has a form which is php generated. He wants to edit it himself like how html forms are done, rename, move text boxes, add text boxes.

But unfortunately the programmer has designed it such that in place of the forms it just says `<php>`. Client insists there must be some way to do this. Any ideas.
I am currently working with Dreamweaver.
Here is part of the code.

```
### BEGIN find any custom field labels ###
$label_title =              'Title';
$label_first_name =         'First';
$label_middle_initial =     'MI';
$label_last_name =          'Last';
$label_address1 =           'Address1';
$label_address2 =           'Address2';
$label_address3 =           'Address3';
$label_city =               'City';
$label_state =              'State';
$label_province =           'Province';
$label_postal_code =        'PostCode';
$label_vendor_lead_code =   'Vendor ID';
$label_gender =             'Gender';
$label_phone_number =       'Phone';
$label_phone_code =         'DialCode';
$label_alt_phone =          'Alt. Phone';
$label_security_phrase =    'Show';
$label_email =              'Email';
$label_comments =           'Comments';

<table width="550px"><tr>
    <td align="right"><font class="body_text">
    <?php

    if ($label_title == '---HIDE---')
        {echo "</td><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"5\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"title\" id=\"title\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "$label_title: </td><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"5\"><font class=\"body_text\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" name=\"title\" id=\"title\" maxlength=\"4\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}
    if ($label_first_name == '---HIDE---')
        {echo "&nbsp; <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "&nbsp; $label_first_name: <input type=\"text\" size=\"17\" name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" maxlength=\"30\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}
    if ($label_middle_initial == '---HIDE---')
        {echo "&nbsp; <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"middle_initial\" id=\"middle_initial\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "&nbsp; $label_middle_initial: <input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" name=\"middle_initial\" id=\"middle_initial\" maxlength=\"1\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}
    if ($label_last_name == '---HIDE---')
        {echo "&nbsp; <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "&nbsp; $label_last_name: <input type=\"text\" size=\"23\" name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" maxlength=\"30\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}

    echo "</td></tr><tr><td align=\"right\"><font class=\"body_text\">";

    if ($label_address1 == '---HIDE---')
        {echo " </td><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"5\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"address1\" id=\"address1\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "$label_address1: </td><td align=\"left\" colspan=5><font class=\"body_text\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"85\" name=\"address1\" id=\"address1\" maxlength=\"100\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}

    echo "</td></tr><tr><td align=\"right\"><font class=\"body_text\">";

    if ($label_address2 == '---HIDE---')
        {echo " </td><td align=\"left\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "$label_address2: </td><td align=\"left\"><font class=\"body_text\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" maxlength=\"100\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}

    echo "</td><td align=\"right\"><font class=\"body_text\">";

    if ($label_address3 == '---HIDE---')
        {echo " </td><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"3\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"address3\" id=\"address3\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "$label_address3: </td><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"3\"><font class=\"body_text\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"45\" name=\"address3\" id=\"address3\" maxlength=\"100\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}

    echo "</td></tr><tr><td align=\"right\"><font class=\"body_text\">";

    if ($label_city == '---HIDE---')
        {echo " </td><td align=\"left\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"\" />";}
    else
        {echo "$label_city: </td><td align=\"left\"><font class=\"body_text\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name=\"city\" id=\"city\" maxlength=\"50\" class=\"cust_form\" value=\"\" />";}

    echo "</td><td align=\"right\"><font class=\"body_text\">";
```

Please, any suggestions?

Comment: i believe only Visual Studio allows ppl to edit web forms, web pages visually. seems like a 'no way!' for php

Comment: to edit everything 'visually', perhaps u can try this: http://www.jcxsoftware.com/jcx/vsphp/home

Answer (score 0):

You might use a database to store the values there, add sql statements to your current php file to get the values from the database. You can also implement an edit page which will allow the client to edit the values in the database.

Comment: database is already in use, didn't include coz i thought it wud look complicated. I know how to change labels, delete and stuff bt my client has no php coding experience but wants to do it himself, visually


$stmt="SELECT label_title,label_first_name,label_middle_initial,label_last_name,label_address1,label_vendor_lead_code,label_gender,label_phone_number, from system_settings;";
$rslt=mysql_query($stmt, $link);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($rslt);
if (strlen($row[0])>0) {$label_title = $row[0];}    
if (strlen($row[4])>0) {$label_address1 =   
### END find any custom field labels ###